# How to merge two lists in r to make a list of ranges?

Tags: r, list, range

I have lists in R as follows:

```
start <- c(1, 5, 11)
end <- c(2, 9, 13)
```

how do I concatenate them to make a list of non-contiguous ranges in this manner:

`c(1:2, 5:9, 11:13)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Map`

```
> Map(`:`, start, end)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 11 12 13
```

or with `unlist` in addition

```
> unlist(Map(`:`, start, end))
 [1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 11 12 13
```

---

A more efficient way might be using `sequence`

```
> sequence(end - start + 1, start)
 [1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 11 12 13
```

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate the ranges from the start and end lists in R to create a list of non-contiguous ranges as you've shown, you can use a loop or an lapply function. Here's how you can achieve that using the lapply function:

```
start <- c(1, 5, 11)
end <- c(2, 9, 13)

result <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) start[i]:end[i]))

print(result)
```